# How to remove Alexa skill error for Sorry, I don't know that one

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

Why? Amazon Alexa showing error "**Sorry, I don't know that one.**"

It is node js code
where, alexa is not working....
I don't know why throwing error

```js
const spiderman_Handler =  {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
        return request.type === 'IntentRequest' && request.intent.name === 'spiderman' ;
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
        const responseBuilder = handlerInput.responseBuilder;
        let sessionAttributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();

        let say = 'spiderman bio';


        return responseBuilder
            .speak(say)
            .reprompt('Hey! Want to know about other avengers, It will be fun...' + say)
            .getResponse();
    },
};
```

Check out this code

launch editor:

```
const LaunchRequest_Handler =  {
        canHandle(handlerInput) {
            const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
            return request.type === 'LaunchRequest';
        },
        handle(handlerInput) {
            const responseBuilder = handlerInput.responseBuilder;

            let say = 'hello!!! You are here for information about your favorite avenger, Nice to see you here. Which Avenger is your favorite?';
            let skillTitle = capitalize(invocationName);
            return responseBuilder
                .speak(say)
                .reprompt('try again, ' + say)
                .withStandardCard('Welcome!', 
                  'Hello!\nThis is a card for your skill, ' + skillTitle,
                   welcomeCardImg.smallImageUrl, welcomeCardImg.largeImageUrl)
                .getResponse();
        },
    };
```

Comment: Can you explain your Problem? With a question like this no one can help you! -- Add some Code etc. and [visit how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: is it compuslory to name amazon skill and invocation same name?

skill name; my favorite avenger
invocation name:favorite avenger

Comment: Launch handler :

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your question. Alexa says

> "Sorry, I don't know that one."

when Alexa skill does not understand your question.

The ability of Alexa skill to understand different questions depends on the intents that you have configured in the skill. If you ask your Alexa skill a question that is configured to be matched to an intent then it should not give you the Sorry message. If it is not able to match the user input with any of the intents configured then you will get the Sorry message, which is generally configured under Default Fallback Intent.

Comment: but its replying not for any question at start only thrwing error for launch of alexa skill  When user speaks "Alexa, open my first avenger"

Comment: Most likely your lambda/webservice is not providing a valid response to the LaunchRequest. Have you checked the request/response in the alexa simulator.

Comment: but how can i check if its not starting

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your invocation name itself.
If your skill is in the development and not yet live on any skill store here are a few things you can do :

1. Make sure the invocation name that you are using is the same
   invocation name that you have defined for your skill.
2. Make sure that the account you are using to create the skill on developer console is the same account that is being used for the device. If not you will need to add the account on the device as the beta tester of the skill you have built. Please see https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/skills-beta-testing-for-alexa-skills.html.
3. if the account is same on both device and in the developer console,
   please re-check if the locale of the device is the same as the
   locale you've built the skill in.
4. If it doesn't help, go to testing
   tab of your skill in the developer console. Try disabling and
   enabling the testing for the skill. It is mostly in the case if you
   have changed the invocation name of the skill recently.